# Передача переменной в класс

Tags: php

Есть такая функция в коде...

```
$email = 'ssss@ssss.ss'
function (Vanchelo\Mailer\Message $message) {
    $message->to('aaaaaa89@gmail.com');
    $message->subject('aaa');
}
```

Как в эту функцию передать переменную email с мылом??

Comment: было на днях уже, для начала надо прочитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php), там есть примеры

Comment: Не дубликат. Есть тонкости.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, какие тонкости? Анонимная функция, надо в ней получить доступ к переменной, используем `use`. В чем отличие от того вопроса?

Comment: В документации есть всё. А тот вопрос сначала мне не понравился, а потом и вовсе пропал.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, но проблема-то одна, никто не мешает дать нормальный ответ в том вопросе, если ответ вам кажется недостаточно хорошим. Это лучше, чем несколько ответов разбросанных по разным вопросам. А автору этого вопроса я уже дал ссылку на документацию, так что он получит необходимые сведения (если, конечно, прочитает доки)

Comment: @BOPOH не вижу того вопроса

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, над вопросом: *на данный вопрос уже ответили" и ссылка на сам вопрос

Comment: Значит, у меня нет доступа